# How to get a list of the <li> elements in an <ul> with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gui-testing

I'm using Selenium WebDriver using Python for UI tests and I want to check the following HTML:

```
<ul id="myId">
    <li>Something here</li>
    <li>And here</li>
    <li>Even more here</li>
</ul>
```

From this unordered list I want to loop over the elements and check the text in them. I selected the ul-element by its `id`, but I can't find any way to loop over the `<li>`-children in Selenium.

Does anybody know how you can loop over the `<li>`-childeren of an unordered list with Selenium (in Python)?

Comment: Please provide the `html` or at least a sample

Comment: The HTML was buried due to missing indents.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use the `.find_elements_by_` method.

For example,

```
html_list = self.driver.find_element_by_id("myId")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    text = item.text
    print text
```

Comment: By having a variable named `list` you are shadowing a built-in `list` which may cause very weird problems on the way.

Comment: Mark, thanks! That seems to work perfectly well. Just one last question; there is actually a link within the tag: `<li><a href="#">some link</a></li>`, and I expected `print item.text` to print that link, but it doesn't print anything. Would you know how I would be able to get the html of the link, or maybe select the link and print out the text of the link? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @alecxe I complete agree, but no-one should just copy-paste. :) But I've edited the variable just in case.

Comment: This no longer works. Will share an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 5):

Strangely enough, I had to use this get_attribute()-workaround in order to see the content:

```
html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("myId")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
for item in items:
    print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension:

```
# Get text from all elements
text_contents = [el.text for el in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@id='myId']/li")]
# Print text
for text in text_contents:
    print(text)
```